# Derive template arguments from other argument but keep intelli sense

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Let's assume I have the following classes:

```
template<typename A> class Foo { ... };
template<typename A, typename B = Foo<A>> class Bar { ... };
```

**Bar** is virtual, and it can be derived with many different arguments for A and B. The template's purpose is to provide intelli-sense for the derivations. I do not want to use interfaces for A and B since they have nothing in common. Also, it would cause a lot of unnecessary casting.

The problem is that I also want to provide various algorithms that use Bar, some generic ones, and some are specialized. Something I tried looks like this:

```
template<typename A, typename B = Foo<A>, typename BarType = Bar<A, B>>
class Algorithm
{
    void doWork(BarType& bar) { ... };
};
```

What I want to do is pass a derivation from Bar to the Algorithm, and it should automatically detect the arguments A and B. For example:

```
class BarDerivation : Bar<int, Foo<int>> { ... };
Algorithm<BarDerivation> alg;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15026041/4135142) provides a solution using type-traits, the problem is that Algorithm would lose the information that BarType is from type Bar.
I'm not certain if what I'm doing is the best approach for what I want to achieve. So is there a solution that solves my problem, or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler would be to add alias in Foo/Bar:

```
template<typename A> class Foo { using type = A; };
template<typename A, typename B = Foo<A>> class Bar { using T1 = A; using T2 = B; };

class Derived : Bar<int, Foo<float>> { /*...*/ };

template <typename BarType>
class Algorithm
{
    using A = typename BarType::T1;
    using B = typename BarType::T2;

    void doWork(BarType& bar) { ... };
};
```

Comment: That's the solution from the answer I linked in my question.
Is there a way to express that BarType is derived from Bar, such that developers get Intellisense when using it?

Comment: Possibly with C++20 concept, but mostly requires to duplicate `Bar`/`Foo` interface in concept.